# Open URL in new window with replacing exist content

Tags: url, replace, window, window.open

I am using window.open() to open new window. Everytime when i click, in the same exist window but replacing the existing content.

I am using the code is,

window.open("url", "test","resizable=yes,height="",width="",top=15,left=15") ;

The code is properly working upto two clicks. when i click third time, the url of the existing window is not changing.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Are you trying to change the content of your new window? Or create a new window every time you click the link?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to change the content of new window.

Comment: Read up on how you can manipulate window.open instances: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Yes, based on the above link i given the name test as second parameter. But upto two clicks only the exist content changing. from third click nothing change.

Comment: Could you provide the full code where you create the new window and then update its contents? It would be good if you could make a jsfiddle with it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `_blank` in the definition of `window.open()` method to open your url in new window.